# Stoping a FadeIn Animation on click and FadeOut on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having issues stopping a fadeIn animation on click. What happen is when the button is pressed the animation fades in but 2 seconds later fades out. Below is my code and I can not figure out how to stop fadeIn on click and then fadeOut on click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#menu").fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#menu").fadeOut("slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f2z6bxk5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `click` event on `#toggle` element is bound twice and both the handlers will run when clicked.

Use `fadeToggle` with `stop`

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pwz1y2ss/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#menu").stop(true, true).fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, I was just reading into .stop function @Tushar